# Can I use MySQL5.7 json datatype to create json diff of two json fields?

Tags: java, mysql, json, mysql-5.7

MySQL newly introduced json datatype in their latest release of MySQL5.7. I have a project in which I need to store the json diff of two json fields in the same row. I was doing it using controller but one of my colleague suggested me to use the new feature of MySQL. I searched a lot in the MySQL documentation but didn't find anything relevant to this json diff. So, I am now posting it in Stack Overflow to know is there any possibility to do this in MySQL5.7.